# Achartengine, 2 x axis labels values using TimeChartView

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am using Achartengine to draw a chart where the X values are date type.
I am wondering if it is possible to show two labels in the X axis, one for the time, e.g: (12:30) and above the date, e.g: (2013-09)

what I would like to do is something like this:

```
-------------------------------------- (x axis)
10:10     10:30     10:40      10:58   (first x label (time))
    2009-05             2009-05        (second x label (date))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the labels on several levels, but you can definitely add any number of custom labels you need:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```